# Is it possible to tokenize all except pre-defined words?

Tags: python, regex, text, nlp

I want to tokenise a sentence but keep the pre-defined words intact. e.g.

```
"i went to university of abc and had a wonderful time there!"
```

into

```
["i", "went", "to", "university of abc", "and", "had", "a", "wonderful", "time", "there", "!"]
```

As `"university of abc"` being the pre-defined words.

I couldn't find such parameter or control in any of the NLTK tokenisers. Any way I can hack to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than split use match using thisregex:

```
(university of abc|\w+|[^\w\s]+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qV5yH8/1)

You can add more pre-defined words at LHS of regex like one shown above.

Comment: Thanks. Can I set the LHS of regex to be any pre-defined words? i.e. W = "university of abc" and then have the variable W somewhere in the regex?

Comment: You can just build the regex using string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regexp regular expression tokenizer and write a regex that, say, splits on all white space that's not part of `"the university of abc."` That's going to be a hassle, though- the hack-y approach is probably just to either pass through the text or write a regex that replaces `"the university of abc"` with `"the-university-of-abc"` or some other string that won't get broken into separate tokens (depending on which tokenizer you're using).